# Change default gender for Windows Emojie picker (WIN+".")

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, emoji

Windows 10/11 has an emoji keyboard accessible by typing: `Windows logo key`  + `. (period)`:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-keyboard-tips-and-tricks-588e0b72-0fff-6d3f-aeee-6e5116097942

When I press `WIN+.`, and type `shrug` I'm presented with two options:

[Image of Emoji Picker after typing `shrug`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQIXH.png)

- Woman shrugging
- Man shrugging

It seems to default to Woman Shrugging. Is there a way to change the default to Man Shrugging for my windows installation?